# Schottky Diode for back EMF

Tags: diodes

I need some advice choosing a suitable SMD schottky diode for my PWM driven motor to handle back EMF. Normal operation of the motor is around 300mA with a start-up current of around 1.2 Amps. What key parameters within a data-sheet do I need to look for to suite my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> *I need some advice choosing a suitable SMD schottky diode for my PWM
> driven motor to handle back EMF.*

Don't worry about it being a schottky, in fact, there are little reasons to use one because low forward volt drop is of no-importance when suppressing back emf whereas high reverse leakage current (as is often the case with a schottky diode) can be problematic in some designs.

> *What key parameters within a data-sheet do I need to look for to suite
> my application.*

- Reverse voltage 1.5 x greater than maximum power supply voltage
- Switching speed unimportant
- Continuous current rating 1.5 x greater than stall current of motor
- Power rating about 1 volt x maximum current rating (volts x amps = watts)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andu. So with my PWM frequency being around 10KHz - 20KHz, I should be okay with Zener diodes for handling back EMF?

Comment: You need a diode in series with a zener diode so I’m not feeling a good vibe about that idea but, you may have a cunning plan so, show your proposed circuit.